# Is it good practice to cast objects to dynamic so the correct overloaded method is called?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, coding-style

My question is about whether what follows is an appropriate use of the `dynamic` keyword in C# 4.

I have some helper methods that provide a more useful representation of various objects than their standard `ToString` methods do, which I use for unit testing. Here is a simplified example:

```
public static string PrettyPrint<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return string.Join(", ", list);
}

// Needed because string is IEnumerable<char>, to prevent
// "Hello" -> "H, e, l, l, o"
public static string PrettyPrint(string s)
{
    return s;
}

public static string PrettyPrint(object o)
{
    return o.ToString();
}
```

I use them something like this:

```
public static void PrettyPrinting()
{
    object[] things = { 1, "Hello", new int[] {1, 2, 3} };

    foreach (dynamic item in things)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PrettyPrint(item));
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
1
Hello
1, 2, 3
```

Notice that if I replace the `dynamic` keyword with `object`, I get the following (all the calls are routed through `PrettyPrint(object)`), which is what I am trying to avoid:

```
1
Hello
System.Int32[]
```

So my question is essentially *is this a code smell* or is it legitimate to cast an `object` to `dynamic` in this way?

Comment: +1 Cool edge case of type systems!

Comment: What would the alternatives to this be? foreach loops are the most expensive loops. I'd be interested to see how the CL creates the code for this and how efficient it would be in a real world environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you don't abuse it, [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) like this is part of the reason `dynamic` was added to the language.

Comment: @errorstacks - doesn't var only work with statically typed variables?  I'm pretty sure anything you declare with var has a type that's known at compile time.

Comment: @errorstacks: `var` is not `dynamic` at all. Two entirely different keywords.

Comment: If I may add some candy to the bee hive, var is used when you know the type but are too lazy to type it out ;P
Dynamic is used when at run time you don't know the type. You could build a factory, or sub classes around it to give a stronger foundation, but now it's the argument of rapid development vs. procedure / structure.

Comment: @Ryan `but are too lazy to type it out ;P` - totally, but it's also used—and necessary—when you're projecting an anonymous type :-)

Comment: @Adam Haha. I understand the need of the var keyword, but I have also reviewed countless pieces of code  written by var-happy junior devs...

Comment: @Ryan - `countless pieces of code written by var-happy junior devs...` - yeah, senior devs too.  That stupid keyword is like a Siren Song for many :(

Answer (score 4):

As to your question, I'm not 100% sure as I don't know your teams style of coding. (I also see little comments ;) )

DuckTyping has it's uses - however a developer needs to know what they're doing before using it. Otherwise it's like running with scissors; it could be abused like other keywords in the C# system.

Personally, I'd rather see extension methods, but depending on the developer, his/her arguments and the documentation done I'd probably allow it.

The biggest reason for my hesitation (and this example is pretty tame to some of the ones I've seen online) is it stops you from finding issues at compile time. It requires more QA testing, a lot more boundary testing, and has a higher risk of failure.

Comment: Wow - apparently someone likes to down vote answers that didn't say all positive things about dynamic types haha. Just because it's new and fancy doesn't mean everything about it is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to the exact question, but I would say your code is not very OO, which is another smell.

Ideally you want to call `item.PrettyPrint()` and each item is supposed to return its representation, and override `PrettyPrint`.

Luckily, existing types can be extended with [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). They enable you to add the methods and that's what I would do instead.

If you still want to have the logic for the display of each type in one class, I would combine extension methods with the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

That said, I don't have C# environment so I can't test what I propose. Let me know if you try this, and if it works.

Comment: Hmm... about visitor + extension method, not sure, but I think this could cause a code inside of extension to be like: `... else if (item is string) { visitor.Visit((string)item); } else if (item is IEnumerable) { visitor.Visit((IEnumerable)item) } `